# Can not implicitly convert type 'RDotNet.IntegerVector' to 'int'

Tags: c#, r.net

I want to transmit R result expression to integer variable using this code :

```
int ID_commun = new int();
ID_commun = engine.Evaluate("intersect(intersect(DataIns$Id,DataAch$FrontOfficeUser_Id),intersect(DataDia$UserId,DataCad$FrontOfficeUser_Id))").AsInteger();
```

But I got this error :

> Can not implicitly convert type 'RDotNet.IntegerVector' to 'int'

How resolve it? thanks!

Comment: What is the type of the return value from `engine.Evaluate`? In any case, it is clear that the compiler sees that you're trying to place a `RDotNet.IntegerVector` value into an `int` variable, do you know where that is? Is it the return value? Is it one of the parameters? As the compiler tries to tell you it cannot do that so you need to figure out **which integer value you want from that vector** instead. This is most likely not someone here can help you with, *you* need to know which value you want and why.

Comment: The return value of engine.Evaluate(...).AsInteger() is an IntegerVector. If you know that there is only one value in this vector, you can get simply call
    `ID_commun = engine.Evaluate("intersect(intersect(DataIns$Id,DataAch$FrontOfficeUser_Id),intersect(DataDia$UserId,DataCad$FrontOfficeUser_Id))").AsInteger().Single();`

Comment: @michivo, thanks , yes it's a vector not an integer ! how could i get the vector result without error , how can i define the vector please?

Comment: @User2018 as I said, just call `.Single()` on your IntegerVector if your IntegerVector has only one value in it, and you will get this value from the IntegerVector as an int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
var ID_commun = engine.Evaluate("intersect(intersect(DataIns$Id,DataAch$FrontOfficeUser_Id),intersect(DataDia$UserId,DataCad$FrontOfficeUser_Id))").AsInteger();
```